# How to join multiple columns into one in sas

Tags: sas, dataset, join

I have a time series SAS dataset and I want to transfer it to vertical dataset.

My data looks like..

```
ID A2009 A2010 A2011 A2012
1      1     2     3     4  
2      1     2     3     4   
3      1     2     3     4   
4      1     2     3     4   
5      1     2     3     4    

data multcol;
infile datalines;
input ID A2009 A2010 A2011 A2012 A2013;
return;
datalines;
1 1 2 3 4 5
2 1 2 3 4 5
3 1 2 3 4 5
4 1 2 3 4 5
5 1 2 3 4 5
;
run;

proc print data=multcol noobs;
run;
```

I search the web only find someone's solution as following.Not worked.
But my dataset is too large, this method shut down my computer.

```
data cmbcol(keep=a orig_varname orig_obsnum);
set multcol;
array myvars _numeric_;
do i = 2 to dim(myvars);
orig_varname = vname(myvars(i));
orig_obsnum = _n_;
A = myvars(i);
output;
end;
run;

proc print data=cmbcol ;
title 'cmbcol';
run;

proc sort data=cmbcol;
by orig_varname a;
run;

proc print data=cmbcol noobs;
title 'cmbcol';
run;
```

And I want them to become like this.

```
ID  t  t+1  
1   1   2    
2   1   2    
3   1   2 
4   1   2   
5   1   2  
1   2   3
2   2   3
3   2   3
4   2   3
5   2   3
1   3   4
2   3   4
3   3   4
4   3   4
5   3   4
```

How can we do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The idea here is to help people with their code not actually doing their work.  Please show us some code so people can help you.

Comment: That is a really weird structure. Look at transpose to get your t column and then you can use a few ways to generate your lead (t+1) variable.  There are multiple solutions on here. As mentioned, try something and then someone will help with code.

Comment: Sorry. I edit the post. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an unusual data structure for sure, but you could achieve this using the following macro (adjust to your needs).

```
options validvarname = any;

%macro transp;
  %let i = 2009;
  %do %while (&i <= 2011);
    %let j = %eval(&i + 1);
    data part_&i(rename = (A&i = t A&j = 't+1'n));
      set multcol(keep =  ID A&i A&j);
    run;
    %let i = %eval(&i + 1);
  %end;

  data combined;
    set part_:;
  run;

  proc datasets nolist nodetails;
    delete part_:;
  quit;
%mend transp;

%transp
```

Comment: Thank you so so so much!!!! It works!!! I learn a lot from you answers, and I also learn how to expand it. Thank you again!!

Comment: Glad it works for you. Thanks for your feedback, and I also learn from people's questions! :)